# Android tab images are not fitting in tabs

Tags: android, tabs

I am working on android app having tabs.I have done with the implementation but I am facing a problem.Images are not being fit on tabs.

**Here is my java code:**

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.tv.allies.FriendsScreen;
import com.tv.servercommunication.IServerResponse;
import com.tv.setting.SettingActivity;
import com.tv.socialgoal.R;
import com.tv.socialgoal.profile.ProfileScreen;
import com.tv.task.TaskListActivity;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class TabViewActivity extends TabActivity implements IServerResponse{
    private static final String INBOX_SPEC = "Inbox";

    private static final String OUTBOX_SPEC = "Outbox";
    private static final String PROFILE_SPEC = "Profile";
    private static final String SETTING_SPEC = "Setting";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("one")
                .setIndicator("",
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.missions_btn_up))
                        .setContent(
                                new Intent(this, TaskListActivity.class)
                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));
        TabSpec outboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(OUTBOX_SPEC);

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("two")
                .setIndicator("",
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.allies_btn_up))
                        .setContent(new Intent(this, FriendsScreen.class)));

        TabSpec setting = tabHost.newTabSpec(OUTBOX_SPEC);
        outboxSpec.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_btn_up));
        Intent outboxIntent = new Intent(this, ProfileScreen.class);
        outboxSpec.setContent(outboxIntent);

        // Profile Tab
        TabSpec profileSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(PROFILE_SPEC);
        profileSpec.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.settings_btn_up));
        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class);
        profileSpec.setContent(profileIntent);

        tabHost.addTab(outboxSpec); // Adding Outbox tab
        tabHost.addTab(profileSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public void serverResponse(String response, int processid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**Here is tab xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="#3399FF"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

**Here is screen short:**

[image]

How all tab images could fit in each tab?

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your question is a tricky thing. For setting tabs background and images as according to your requirement you have to use custom xml of images which you have to set on your tabs

1) **For tab background** :-

a) Create an xml in your drawable folder and copy paste following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_green" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_blue" />
</selector>
```

This xml will work same as xml we use for buttons. on pressed state and for normal state.
Name this xml as tab_bg.xml

b) In your java file use following in code for tabhost use following method and pass your tabhost instance in this method

```
public void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
        for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
            tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg); //unselected
        }
    }
```

2) **Secondly for the tab icon** :- use the xml like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/settings_btn_down"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/settings_btn_up" />
</selector>
```

Name this xml as settings_tab_xml.xml . and in your code

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("two")
                .setIndicator("",
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.xml.settings_tab_xml))
                        .setContent(new Intent(this, FriendsScreen.class)));
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

use proper images in tabs as per resolution

use the following link to generate tab images .[[check this]](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-tab.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=example):

Comment: @ricintech  check this http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/